# Nothing happens when sending a mail with (command line) sendmail

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, sendmail, mailbox

I want to set a mail server that can send mail with `sendmail`. Here is what I have done exactly

```
 service postfix start
 sendmail < mymail
```

where `mymail` contains

```
to:my@mail.com
from:random@mail.com
subject: None
None
```

With a packet capture, I see that nothing is sent. `postfix` is running on port 25 and I haven't touch the configuration after postfix installation.

**Why is the mail not sent and how can I send a mail with sendmail?**

Comment: sendmail user@example.com  < /tmp/email.txt   (email.txt = <br>subject<br>text)  (replace <br> with empty line feed)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I obviously forget my mail when writting the command. With `sendemail`, I get  the error: `ERROR => TLS setup failed: SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed`

Comment: You may check `/var/log/mail.*` for debugging.

Answer (score 4):

1) Instruct sendmail to look for recipients in message headers (`-t`) and ignore single dot line as end of email (`-i`).  Without `-t` sendmail expects to get recipients' list via command line.

```
sendmail -i -t < mymail
```

2) Insert empty line between headers and body in the message (`mymail` file)

```
to:my@mail.com
from:random@mail.com
subject: None

None
```

[Postfix manual sendmail(1)](http://www.postfix.org/mailq.1.html)